# Sparse index in Mongodb - How it works

Tags: mongodb

According to docs, if I create a sparse index, documents not having the specified field won't be referenced by the index. However, what happens if those documents (those that don't have that field) are updated and the indexed field is added? Do they become referenced by the sparse index?

Comment: Yes, the index is modified every time you change a document, it is all done atomically on the document save

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it will be added to the index. It would be kind of useless if it wasn't. In the future you can test this yourself by doing `db.col.find().explain()`.

Comment: This is the thing: What is the point then to create a "regular" index (which references all documents, even if they don't have the indexed field) in the first place? Wouldn't be better to use ALWAYS a sparse index to save space?

Comment: @borjagvo if you never want to query documents that don't have that field then sure, why not?

Comment: I think the point is why does normal index even exist if there are sparse indexes? Sparse sounds like it handles both cases. Normal indexes make no sense then.